# How can I print the json content of the response from post request in Alamofire in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

Ok, so I'm using alamofire and the parameters I'm passing are valid. Here is the code so far:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebservice.com", parameters: myparameters)
.response { (request, response, data, error) in
    if(error != nil){
        print("error= \(error)")
    }else{
        print("there was no error so far ")
        print(data)
        var json = JSON(data!)

        print(json) //prints unknown
        print(json["id"]) //prints null      
        }
    }
}
```

I tried different things but so far nothing worked. I'm using alamofire and swiftyjson, the response json that comes from webservice is:

```
{
  "id": "432532gdsg",
  "username": "gsdgsdg"
}
```

and I want to print both values separately in case of success. How can I do it?

Comment: Let's try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33720060/2227743 (it's about the init for JSON() and, if I guess right, may help you)

Comment: yeah, that was that, thank you! I can either remove this question or - when you post it as an answer - I will accept it and the question gets closed by itself, your call, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! The two questions are different, so I've made a specific answer for this one too. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue comes from this line:

```
var json = JSON(data!)
```

The `JSON()` initializer from SwiftyJSON can take several type of inputs.

When you don't specify the type in the init, SwiftyJSON tries to infer the type itself.

Unfortunately it sometimes fails *silently* because it will have misinterpreted the input.

So, when using SwiftyJSON with NSData, the solution is to specify the "data:" parameter for the JSON initializer:

```
var json = JSON(data: data!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebservice.com", parameters : myparameters , encoding : .JSON )
    .responseData{ response in
            let json = JSON(data.response.result.value!)
            print(json)
            let id=json["id"]
            let username=json["username"]
            print(id)
            print(username)          
}
```